# I am trying to update and insert multiple google sheets with multiple rows, but not getting the correct API

Tags: salesforce, google-sheets-api, integration, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

I am trying to update and insert multiple Google sheets with multiple rows, using the integration with Salesforce, for this, I need an endpoint (API) by which I can hit the Google Sheet API only once and upsert (insert, update) multiple rows in multiple Google sheets. I was trying to find it on Google but not getting the same. Is there any way by which I can get the actual API?

I tried with the Google Sheet API, which is only for a single sheet and it is working as expected also tried to find an **API** for bulk insertion and update but not getting on Google Sheets API.
I am expecting multiple sheet rows insert and update using a single API call.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Sure Tanaike, 
I am trying to change multiple Google Sheets and their records from Salesforce, using to establish a connection which is known as integration.
I successfully connected both (Salesforce and Google Sheets) and by hitting on the Google Sheet server I am able to create or change a single sheet and single record. But it works when I hit the Google server one by one, but as you know everything is limited, so in Salesforce, there is a limitation that says we only hit the Google sheet server for any request only 100 times in one transaction.

Comment: So, I need a URL (API) of Google Sheets by using it I can send multiple requests on the server at a single time. And change or create multiple Google Sheets or multiple Google Sheets rows at a single request in only one transaction.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I think that there are several approaches to using Sheets API. But, I cannot still understand the detail of your situation. So, I cannot propose a clear answer. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand your question, I have 2 questions. 1. In your situation, what language are you using? 2. Can you provide the sample value you want to put to the Spreadsheet using Sheets API?

Comment: And, as additional information, I thought that this official document might be useful for selecting your expected method of Sheets API at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values).

Comment: Thank you Tanaike for your response.
The answers to your question are:- 1. I am using Apex language which is more similar to Java. 2. For your second question I have to update two Spreadsheets, in the first one [Name = 'Anurag'] and in the second Spreadsheet [Name = 'Tanaike'] on a single server hit.

Also, I already checked the official document but every time (every server hit) I need to add the spreadsheet id which clear that at a time only one spreadsheet will be updated.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.